# Diseñar la estructura de un árbol binario

Tags: c++

no logro entender la estructura que os expongo a continuación sobre un árbol binario.

**Fichero de cabecera Abin**

```
template <typename T> class Abin {
    struct celda; //declaración adelantada privada
public:
    typedef celda* nodo;
    static const nodo NODO_NULO;

    Abin();//constructor
    void crearRaizB(const T& e);
    void insertarHijoIzqdoB(nodo n, const T& e);
    void insertarHijoDrchoB(nodo n, const T& e);
    void eliminarHijoIzqdoB(nodo n);
    void eliminarHijoDrchoB(nodo n);
    void eliminarRaizB();
    ~Abin(); //destructor
    bool arbolVacioB() const;
    T elemento(nodo n) const; //acceso a elto, lectura
    T& elemento(nodo n); //acceso a elto, lectura/escritura
    nodo raizB() const;
    nodo padreB(nodo n) const;
    nodo hijoIzqdoB(nodo n) const;
    nodo hijoDrchoB(nodo n) const;
    Abin(const Abin<T>& a); // ctor. de copia
    Abin<T>& operator =(const Abin<T>& a); //asignación de árboles
private:
    struct celda{
        T elto;
        nodo padre, hizq, hder;
        celda(const T& e, nodo p = NODO_NULO): elto(e), padre(p), hizq(NODO_NULO), hder(NODO_NULO) {}
    };
    nodo r; //nodo raíz del árbol
    void destruirNodos(nodo& n);
    nodo copiar(nodo n);
};
```

Entiendo que tenemos una estructura celda con cuatro elementos:

- `elto`: elemento (información de tipo `char`, `int`...) que va a contener nuestro nodo.
- nodos `padre`, `hizq`, `hder`: almacena un entero en cada campo que corresponde a la posición en la que se encuentra el elemento.

**Mis dudas:**

```
typedef celda* nodo;
```

¿Qué es exactamente esa línea?
¿En qué línea está definido el tipo nodo?

Si tuvierais algún enlace para lograr entenderlo mejor os lo agradezco porque con todo esto de golpe, la teoría la sé, pero en la práctica me pierdo.

Comment: Esa línea es un alias de tipo, te dice que bajo la etiqueta `nodo` tendrás un puntero a `celda`.

Comment: Amigo cambia la pregunta que a mi parecer la tienes mal, estas preguntando sobre `typedef`, que que pon eso, no pongas diseñar un árbol binario porque tu duda se trata es sobre los alias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Entiendo que tenemos una estructura celda con cuatro elementos:

Efectivamente `celda` es una estructura con cuatro variables miembro, donde `elto` se espacializa en el tipo a usar por la plantilla (`int`, `char`, etc).

Sin embargo `padre`, `hizq` y `hder` **no son enteros** sino **punteros**.

La clase `Albin` está creando un mapa de nodos (cada nodo es de tipo `celda`), donde cada uno de estos nodos conoce tanto a su padre como a sus nodos izquierdo y derecho. Este diseño te permite moverte de forma bidireccional dentro del árbol (de arriba abajo y viceversa).

> ¿Qué es exactamente esa línea?

Esa línea define un alias y dicho alias actua exactamente como su nombre indica. Un alias no es un tipo nuevo sino una referencia a un tipo dado. En este caso se está creando un alias llamado `nodo` que sustituye al tipo `celda*`.

Por si te lo preguntas, los alias sirven para mejorar la legibilidad del código... cuando se usan con criterio. Un ejemplo muy claro se puede encontrar al tratar con punteros a función:

```
void func(int,char)
{ std::cout << "func(int,char);\n"; }

void ejecutaFuncion( void (*funcPtr)(int,char) )
{
  funcPtr(1,'c');
}

int main()
{
  ejecutaFuncion(func);
}
```

La sintaxis va quedando más y más fea cuanto más compleja es la llamada a `func`. Este código puede quedar mucho más limpio si se usa un alias:

```
typedef FuncPtr void(*)(int,char);

void ejecutaFuncion( FuncPtr funcPtr )
{
  funcPtr(1,'c');
}
```

De esta forma por muy compleja que sea la definición del puntero a función, la declaración de la función `ejecutaFuncion` no solo permanece constante sino que además es facil de entender.

> ¿En qué línea está definido el tipo nodo?

Ya hemos visto que `nodo` es un alias y que lo estás definiendo en esa misma línea.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> typedef celda* nodo;
> ```
>
> ¿Qué es exactamente esa línea? ¿En qué línea está definido el tipo nodo?

Ese es el menor problema del código que has compartido, pero empezaremos por resolver esa duda. Esa línea es una declaración `typedef` que según [el estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) (traducción y resaltados míos):

> #### 10.1.3 El especificador `typedef`
>
> 1 [...] Un nombre declarado con el especificador `typedef` es un *nombre-typedef*. Dentro del ámbito de su declaración un *nombre-typedef* es sintácticamente equivalente a una palabra clave y nombra al tipo asociado con el identificador de la manera que se describe en la Cláusula 11. **Un *nombre-typedef* es entonces, un sinónimo de otro tipo**. Un *nombre-typedef* no introduce un nuevo tipo como lo hace la declaración de una clase o un enumerado. [*Ejemplo*: tras
>
> ```
>  typedef int MILLAS, *KLICKSP;
> ```
>
> las construcciones
>
> ```
> MILLAS distancia;
> extern KLICKSP metricp;
> ```
>
> Son todas declaraciones correctas; el tipo de `distancia` es `int` y el de `metricp` es “puntero a `int`”. — fin del ejemplo ]

Así pues tu línea `typedef celda* nodo;` está creando un sinónimo del tipo `celda*` con nombre `nodo`, en otras palabras: para el compilador `nodo` y puntero a `celda` (`celda*`) serán exactamente lo mismo.

Este tipo de declaración de sinónimos se considera confusa porque no sigue el formato de otros constructos de C++, así que en el estándar C++11 se añadió una forma diferente de definir sinónimos:

```
using nodo = celda*;
```

La instrucción anterior es equivalente a tu `typedef` y es más fácil de entender por seguir el formato de asignación habitual al que el lenguaje nos tiene acostumbrados, en cambio no permite hacer definiciones múltiples (como vemos en el ejemplo de `typedef` del estándar), pero en contrapartida permite hacer sinónimos plantilla.

---

#### No hay encapsulamiento.

El código que compartes denota un diseño terrible que ignora por completo los principios de [encapsulamiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulamiento_(inform%C3%A1tica)) al dar detalles de la implementación interna mediante la interfaz pública. Por otro lado, no contiene ni un sólo método de búsqueda mediante tipo almacenado (`T`) si no que en todos los casos espera recibir un `nodo` para hacer cualquier operación; en mi opinión, deberías repasar toda la implementación y ver otros ejemplos de árboles binarios.

Answer (score 1):

El tipo `nodo` no está definido como tal, lo que tienes es un puntero a la estructura `celda`.

Es decir, `nodo` es lo mismo que `celda`, pero le asigna la palabra/alias `nodo` que es el que utiliza en el resto del código para que al utilizarlo en el árbol sea mas fácil de entender. Por ejemplo, es mas visible poner `nodo padre` que si pusiese `celda padre`.

Answer (score 1):

[Typedef](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/other_data_types/)

> Un alias de tipo es un nombre diferente por el cual se puede identificar un tipo. En C++, cualquier tipo válido puede ser alias para que pueda ser referido con un identificador diferente.

En C++ se existen dos maneras de definir un alias, la primera que es heredado de C, es con typedef:

`typedef tipo_dato_existente alias_de_tipo_dato`

y la otra manera que ya es de C++,

`using alias_de_tipo_dato = tipo_dato_existente`.

Que beneficios tiene el utilizar un alias, hay varias, una de tantas es que separar tus tipos de dato de la arquitectura del tu pc y funcionamiento del Sistema Operativo, por ejemplo el tipo de dato `int` es un tipo de dato de 32 bits en procesadores de 32 bits, pero en un procesador de 64bits, este suele tener 32 o 64bits y esto puede afectar el funcionamiento de tu programa, si este es multiplataforma, así que se puede crear un alias para el tipo de dato que se necesita dependiendo del sistema, sin necesidad de cambiar todo tu programa, simplemente cambias el tipo de dato que apunta el alias y listo.

esa línea lo que hace es define un alias llamado `nodo` el cual es un puntero a una estructura llamada `celda`.

Comment: Lo que dices de "*y la otra manera que ya es C++*" no es totalmente correcto. `using` únicamente está disponible a partir de C++11. En C++98 (o incluso C++03) no puedes usar `using` pese a programar en C++...