# Entender la clase árbol binario

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos

poco a poco, estoy intentando ([como el otro día pregunté](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/145271/dise%C3%B1ar-la-estructura-de-un-%C3%A1rbol-binario)) comprender la clase árbol binario. Si pregunto mucho sobre ello es por esto mismo, disculpad si pregunto en demasía.

Os dejo la clase (sin las cabeceras de las funciones):

```
#ifndef ABIN_H
#define ABIN_H

#include <cassert>

using namespace std;


template <typename T> class Abin {
    struct celda; //declaración adelantada privada
public:
    typedef celda* nodo;
    static const nodo NODO_NULO;
    Abin();//constructor
    void crearRaizB(const T& e);
    void insertarHijoIzqdoB(nodo n, const T& e);
    void insertarHijoDrchoB(nodo n, const T& e);
    void eliminarHijoIzqdoB(nodo n);
    void eliminarHijoDrchoB(nodo n);
    void eliminarRaizB();
    ~Abin(); //destructor
    bool arbolVacioB() const;
    T elemento(nodo n) const; //acceso a elto, lectura
    T& elemento(nodo n); //acceso a elto, lectura/escritura
    nodo raizB() const;
    nodo padreB(nodo n) const;
    nodo hijoIzqdoB(nodo n) const;
    nodo hijoDrchoB(nodo n) const;
    Abin(const Abin<T>& a); // ctor. de copia
    Abin<T>& operator =(const Abin<T>& a); //asignación de árboles

private:
    struct celda{
        T elto;
        nodo padre, hizq, hder;
        celda(const T& e, nodo p = NODO_NULO): elto(e), padre(p), hizq(NODO_NULO), hder(NODO_NULO) {}
    };
    nodo r; //nodo raíz del árbol
    void destruirNodos(nodo& n);
    nodo copiar(nodo n);
};
```

De momento, las dudas que me asaltan son:

1) La estructura celda dentro de la propia clase, esto no lo entiendo bien, sé que un objeto de tipo (clase) árbol binario, tendrá varias estructuras (que son celdas) y cada una sus atributos (puntero padre, puntero hijos..)
Pero en realidad una estructura al ser prácticamente una clase, ¿es como si estuviera una clase dentro de otra no?

Si pudierais explicarme esto un poco más os lo agradecería.

2) La siguiente línea:

```
celda(const T& e, nodo p = NODO_NULO): elto(e), padre(p), hizq(NODO_NULO), hder(NODO_NULO) {}
```

Esto es si no me equivoco un constructor que inicializa sus atributos, el e al ser constante es obligatorio el uso de la sintaxis de inicialización, pero el nodo o (`NODO_NULO = 0`), ¿Qué está haciendo exactamente con ese puntero? le asigna una dirección vacía? ¿Eso no se haría con `NULL` en lugar de `0`?
Aquí os dejo su definición:

```
template <typename T>
const typename Abin<T>::nodo Abin<T>::NODO_NULO(0);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> La estructura celda dentro de la propia clase, esto no lo entiendo bien, [...], ¿es como si estuviera una clase dentro de otra no?

No es *como si estuviera dentro*, **está dentro**. Uno de los principios del [encapsulamiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulamiento_(inform%C3%A1tica)) es mantener oculto (o inaccesible) lo que un objeto use para si mismo y mantener accesible lo necesario para que el objeto sea manipulado.

Como analogía, imagina un coche: la carrocería te oculta los elementos internos como el motor, la batería, la caja de cambios, los ejes, etcétera...

[image]
<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>Mmm... me pregunto qué pasará si le pego un lametón a la junta de la trócola.</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

No necesitas saber que esos elementos están ahí para usar el coche (no necesitas siquiera verlos) lo único que necesitas saber es dónde están los pedales, la palanca de cambios y el contacto.

De hecho, es probable que tú o cualquiera que use el coche tenga la tentación de manipular los elementos que tenga accesibles, con la posibilidad de derivar en un uso incorrecto de los mismos, cuantas más cosas se puedan manipular más probabilidades hay de que sean manipuladas de manera incorrecta.

Tu clase `Abin` está encapsulando el objeto `celda` porque es una estructura de datos que no tiene sentido ser usada fuera de dicha clase, definiéndola como objeto interno en la zona privada evita que podamos instanciarla:

```
Abin<int>::celda c;
```

> ```
> error: 'struct Abin<int>::celda' is private within this context
>  Abin<int>::celda c;
>             ^~~~~
> ```

Pero hay que tener en cuenta que lo que es privado es el identificador, estás haciendo accesible dicho identificador mediante [el alias `nodo`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/145271/dise%C3%B1ar-la-estructura-de-un-%C3%A1rbol-binario), podrás instanciar objetos `celda` fuera de `Abin` siempre y cuando no uses el identificador:

```
Abin<int>::nodo n;
std::remove_pointer<Abin<int>::nodo>::type c;
decltype(*n) d = *n;
```

En ambos casos, tanto `c` como `d` son de tipo `Abin::celda` ¡pese a que es un tipo interno! Es decir, el alias ha roto el encapsulamiento de `Abin::celda`.

---

> La siguiente línea:
>
> ```
> celda(const T& e, nodo p = NODO_NULO): elto(e), padre(p), hizq(NODO_NULO), hder(NODO_NULO) {}
> ```
>
> Esto es si no me equivoco un constructor que inicializa sus atributos, el e al ser constante es obligatorio el uso de la sintaxis de inicialización, pero el nodo o (`NODO_NULO = 0`), ¿Qué está haciendo exactamente con ese puntero? le asigna una dirección vacía? ¿Eso no se haría con `NULL` en lugar de `0`?

Tienes claros algunos conceptos y otros sin embargo, algo liados. La línea que remarcas es efectivamente un constructor; está usando lo que se conoce como "*lista de inicialización del constructor*", que es la utilidad que ofrece C++ para inicializar los sub-objetos de un objeto antes de que dicho objeto empiece su ciclo de vida. También es cierto que esta utilidad es necesaria para inicializar sub-objetos constantes:

```
struct Mal {
    const int v; // v es un dato constante
    Mal(int valor) {
        v = valor; // Error! No se puede modificar un dato constante
    }
};

struct Bien {
    const int v; // v es un dato constante
    Bien(int valor) :
        v(valor) // Correcto!
    {}
};
```

Pero nada de esto es aplicable a tu estructura `celda` pues no tiene miembros constantes, el siguiente código es equivalente al que tienes<sup>1</sup>:

```
struct celda{
    T elto;
    nodo padre, hizq, hder;
    celda(const T& e, nodo p = NODO_NULO) {
        elto = e;
        padre = p;
        hizq = NODO_NULO;
        hder = NODO_NULO;
    }
};
```

Respecto a asignar `0` a punteros, es una práctica habitual para señalar que dicho puntero no apunta a nada. Pero suele causar confusión, por ejemplo:

```
p = 0;
i = 0;
```

Una de las variables del código anterior es un puntero, pero es difícil de saber cuál de ellas lo es porque se está usando igual que un entero, para evitar este problema se suele usar la macro `NULL` que (dependiendo de la implementación) puede ser `0` o `0L`.

```
p = 0;
i = NULL;
```

Pero el uso de esta macro sólo solventa el problema de legibilidad, a nivel funcional sigue siendo confuso:

```
void puntero(int *) {}
void entero(int) {}

puntero(0);   // Funciona! Aunque le pase un entero!
entero(NULL); // Funciona! Aunque le pase NULL!
```

Para evitar este problema, C++11 incorporó el literal de puntero nulo `nullptr`:

```
void puntero(int *) {}
void entero(int) {}

puntero(0);      // Funciona! 0 sigue siendo convertible a puntero
entero(nullptr); // Error! nullptr no es un entero
```

---

1. Sin embargo, yo prefiero usar la lista de inicialización del constructor.

Answer (score 4):

> ¿es como si estuviera una clase dentro de otra no?

Efectivamente es una clase declarada dentro de otra. Como la clase `celda` está declarada en la parte `private` de `Abin`, únicamente `Abin` podrá crear y utilizar objetos de este tipo.

Si la clase `celda` estuviese declarada en la parte pública de `Albin` podrías crear objetos de tipo `celda` de la siguiente forma:

```
Abin::celda miCelda;
```

Que sería un comportamiento equivalente a si `Abin` fuese un espacio de nombres:

```
namespace Abin
{
  struct celda
  { /* ... */ };
}
```

> Esto es si no me equivoco un constructor que inicializa sus atributos

Correcto

> el e al ser constante es obligatorio el uso de la sintaxis de inicialización

Esta afirmación ya no es tan correcta. `e` no es una constante sino una **referencia** constante. Las referencias se usan para evitar copias innecesarias. Si `e` no fuese una referencia, al crear un objeto de tipo `celda` se crearía un objeto temporal de tipo `T` y después se copiaría su valor en `elto`... mientras que con una referencia evitas el objeto temporal.

> ¿Qué está haciendo exactamente con ese puntero? le asigna una dirección vacía?

Un puntero es una variable que almacena direcciones de memoria... simple y llanamente. Un problema muy común al trabajar con punteros es que los mismos apunten a regiones no válidas de la memoria (no apuntan a datos válidos de la aplicación) y el estándar adoptado para detectar cuando un puntero no es válido es hacer que apunte a la región de memoria 0x0000.

Así es bastante común ver inicializaciones de punteros tal que:

```
int* ptr = 0;
int* ptr = NULL;
int* ptr = nullptr; // C++11 en adelante
```

O comprobaciones del tipo:

```
if( ptr == 0 || !ptr ) // Las dos comparaciones son equivalentes
```

> ¿Eso no se haría con null en lugar de 0?

`NULL` es una macro definida en `stddef.h` de la siguiente forma:

```
#define NULL 0
```

Luego es indiferente usar `NULL` o 0 ya que al binario final irá un 0 en cualquiera de los dos casos.

¿Por qué usar `NULL` entonces? por legibilidad. Si se toma como costumbre usar `NULL` al trabajar con punteros será facil identificarlos en el código:

```
// Encuentra los punteros
a = 0
b = 123
c = NULL
d = b + a
e = c
```

Con C++11 (estándar que data del 2011), apareció `nullptr`. Desde entonces es recomendable abandonar `NULL` y `0` al trabajar con punteros:

```
int* ptr = nullptr;
```

¿Por qué razón?

Porque `nullptr` posee un tipado tal que impide que pueda utilizarse con objetos que no sean punteros:

```
int variable = nullptr; // error de compilación
```

Además tiene la ventaja que evita comportamientos inesperados al trabajar con funciones sobrecargadas:

```
void func(int)
{ std::cout << "int\n"; }

void func(int*)
{ std::cout << "int*\n"; }

int main()
{
  func(0);       // func(int)
  func(NULL);    // func(int)
  func(nullptr); // func(int*)

  int var = 10;
  int* ptr = &var;

  func(var);     // func(int)
  func(ptr);     // func(int*)
}
```